# In React Navigation with Redux, is there a way to update Stack Navigator header components a screen in the stack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm building a native app with Expo that uses React Navigation and Redux. I'm having trouble re-rendering components in the stack navigation header of a screen upon updating from a sibling form screen.
In my Stack Navigator, I have a Home screen and Form screen to create new profiles (dogs) for the user.

The Home screen header has 2 components:

1. headerLeft touchable component that contains an image of the profile
2. headerTitle picker component that has a dropdown of profiles to select from

The Form screen navigates to the Home screen on submitting a new dog, but neither component in the Home screen header gets updated without a hard refresh. The handleSubmit of the Form screen posts to the backend, dispatches actions, and lastly navigation.navigate('Home').

I've tried refactoring Redux dispatches and state, but I can't seem to get it to render properly without a hard refresh. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

I was doing:

```
const [dog, setDog] = useState(useSelector(state => state.dog));
```

And so my state was not changing. I removed useState and now it works.

It was from my lack of understanding of React and Redux.. Thanks.